# Run remote shell daemon as non root user with tab-completion

Tags: shell, telnet

I need to run any "remote shell daemon" (ssh, telnet, netcat, socat... I don't mind) as **non-root user**. The remote shell should provide *tab-completion* and I want to be able to *browse history using arrows*.

I am currently using a netcat-based solution, but I *loose tab-completion* and I am unable to *browse history* using arrows

On server side :

```
# Run the "remote shell daemon"
$ mkfifo fifo
$ nc -l 2000 <fifo | /bin/bash &> fifo
$ rm fifo
```

On client side :

```
# Connect to the remote shell
$ nc $REMOTE_ADDR 2000
```

Adding the `-i` or `-l` argument to bash does not help.

Comment: If you use ssh and your remote shell is properly configured then you should have tab-completion and history browsing. At least I have when I login to my server using Ubuntu 12.04 on both machines.

Comment: I need to run a "remote shell" daemon as **non-root user**. Sshd typically runs as root.

Comment: As long as the config files and the keys are owned by the user running sshd, and you use a port number > 1024 you don't need to run sshd as root.

Comment: Why do you need to run the _daemon_ as a regular user? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Anthon I would also like to bypass the standard unix authentication phase (/etc/passwd, login). I would like to connect to the "remote shell daemon" and directly obtain a shell.

Comment: @Xion345 Is that because you don't want to type a password, or because of delays logging in causes. In the former case you can use a private/public key pair to prevent ssh from prompting you.

Comment: @terdon : I use a computing grid and I don't have a shell access to all nodes of the grid. The only thing I can do is submit scripts to the system (it's Grid Engine), and they will be scheduled on the node I specified. I would like to write a script that would allow me to have a shell access to a node of the grid.

Comment: @Anthon It is because there is no user account I can use in the /etc/passwd file of this machine (the only non-system user in /etc/passwd is root and I don't have root access to this machine).

Comment: It's a compute node in the cluster you're not supposed to have direct access to it.  What specific reason do you need shell access?  If you have some job that you want to run do it through SGE and submit your job as an interactive job.

Comment: @John I developed a script to install Hadoop on a set of SGE nodes and I would like to have access to the Hadoop master node to submit my jobs interactively. `qlogin` and `qrsh` don't work on the grid I am using.

Comment: Can you submit the job "xterm" or "gnome-terminal" to SGE and get it to remote display a terminal to the SGE node? I used to do that trick. In my experience with SGE your job typically ran with your user credentials, can jobs that you run in your SGE write files out? If so what userid are these files being written to disk ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

socat(1) could be of some help.

From http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/machine/penguin-lust/src/socat-1.7.1.2/EXAMPLES:

```
// poor mans 'telnetd' replacement
# socat tcp-l:2023,reuseaddr,fork exec:/bin/login,pty,setsid,setpgid,stderr,ctty
// and here an appropriate client:
$ socat -,raw,echo=0 tcp:172.16.181.130:2023
```

Here, the example uses "login" which obviously requires a root access but I succesfully tested with /bin/zsh. This implies that security is not a problem... Otherwise, as they say in the webpage where I found out this tip, you could use a client authentication with SSL to make sure only you can actually log in.

Answer (score 1):

## Tab completion with netcat:

```
- stty   : change and print terminal line settings  
- echo   : echo input characters  
- icanon : enable erase, kill, werase, and rprnt special characters
- sane   : Revert back default terminal line setting
```

### Command :

`bash-4.3# stty -echo -icanon && nc ... && stty sane`

### Example :

`stty -echo -icanon && nc 0 5000 && stty sane
 Note : 5000 is the port number`

## For more Info you can refer to linux man page :

[*Linux man Page - stty*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty)

[*Linux man Page - netcat*](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)